# Java if/for loop assistance

Tags: java

Below is my code...I am trying to make a countdown timer. Right now it works correctly in terms of counting down in the correct sequential order.  I am trying to figure out how to place an if statement within the code so that is prints 1 minute and ''seconds, instead of 1 minutes and '' seconds

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class countdown {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int minutes;
    System.out.println("Please enter the timer countdown in minutes:");
    minutes = scan.nextInt();

    while (minutes < 1) {
        System.out.print("Invalid entry: Enter 1 or more minutes: ");
        minutes = scan.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = minutes - 1; i >= 0; i--)

    {
        for (int s = 59; s >= 1; s--)

            System.out.println(i + " minutes, " + s + " seconds");
        System.out.println("The timer is done!");

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add an if/else statement in there:

```
for (int i = minutes - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    String minute;
    if(minutes == 1)
        minute = " minute ";
    else
        minute = " minutes ";

    for (int s = 59; s >= 1; s--){
        String seconds;
        if(s == 1)
            seconds = " second";
        else
            seconds = " second";
        System.out.println(i + minute + s + seconds);
    }
}
```

The other answer is probably better, but it uses a different syntax that makes all this code into a short line. They do basically the same thing.

Comment: this definitely works for the i == 1 to minute, but how do I incorporate the s == 1 to second instead of seconds?

Comment: @user3455588 no problem. Welcome to SO by the way. Selecting an answer to your questions is just as important as asking questions around here, so be sure to mark the correct answer on whichever one you found best solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Like this,

```
String minutes = i + (i > 1 ? " minutes" : " minute"); // put this line in outer loop
String seconds = s + (s > 1 ? " seconds" : " second"); // and this line in inner loop

System.out.println(minutes +", "+ seconds);
```

Comment: I think it makes sense to define `minutes` in the outer, not inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

These two if/else statements should work.

```
for (int s = 59; s >= 1; s--)
    {
        if (i == 1)
            System.out.print(i + " minute, ");
        else
            System.out.print(i + " minutes, ");
        if (s == 1)
            System.out.println(s + " second");
        else 
            System.out.println(s + " seconds");
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the help...i was trying the else if and it was not working.